# how to show tags using select2 in select tag using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I want to set the tags in in drop down usning select2. Like i want to put custom e-mail or anything else then it should show as tag.
I am sharing the jsfiddle.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label>Please select items:</label>
    <select ui-select2 multiple ng-model='selectedDaltons'>
        <option ng-repeat="d in daltons" ng-bind="d" value="{{ d }}"></option>
    </select>
</div>




var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.select2']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.daltons = [
        'Joe',
        'William' ,
        'Jack' ,
        'Averell' ,
        'Ma' 
    ];    
    $scope.selectedDaltons = 'joe'; // Averell is preselected 
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hWXBv/179/

Answer (score 2):

In ui-select, you can use the 'tagging' feature, you can even set the tagging-label. 
Check out this link

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select
```

And this plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0
```